# How to use specific table in a join under condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a stored procedure including input parameters, temp tables and joins.

I have `AllocationDetails` temp table in this procedure:

```
;WITH AllocationDetails AS
(
    SELECT
        lastPaymentAllocationDetails.*
    FROM   
        (SELECT 
             *, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [PaymentAllocationGuid] ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [WorkingPeriodTitle] DESC) rowNumber
         FROM 
             ret_vwPaymentAllocationDetails) lastPaymentAllocationDetails
WHERE lastPaymentAllocationDetails.rowNumber = 1
),
```

Then I would like to have another temp table - like this:

```
ValidPaymentAllocations AS
(
    SELECT
        paymentAllocationDetails.[PaymentAllocationGuid],
        paymentAllocation.[RetiredPersonnelGuid],
        MAX(paymentAllocationDetails.ID) AS MaxPaymentAllocationDetailID,
        MAX(paymentAllocationDetails.[Year] * 100 + paymentAllocationDetails.[WorkingPeriodTitle]) AS [WorkingPeriodKey]
    FROM
        ret_PaymentAllocation AS paymentAllocation 
    INNER JOIN
        CASE when(@PaymentCommandType = 1) THEN ret_PaymentAllocationDetails  ELSE AllocationDetails END AS paymentAllocationDetails ON paymentAllocation.[Guid] = paymentAllocationDetails.[PaymentAllocationGuid] 
    INNER JOIN
        ret_PaymentTypes AS paymentTypes ON paymentAllocation.[PaymentTypesGuid] = paymentTypes.[Guid] 
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT MAX(ID) ID FROM ret_PaymentAllocationDetails GROUP BY PaymentAllocationGuid,WorkingPeriodTitle,Year) lastRecord ON LastRecord.Id = paymentAllocationDetails.ID
    WHERE
        ISNULL(paymentAllocation.[Deleted],0) = 0 AND
        paymentAllocation.[RetiredPersonnelGuid] = @SalariedGuid AND
        (paymentAllocationDetails.[Year]  * 100 + paymentAllocationDetails.[WorkingPeriodTitle] <= @Year * 100 + @WorkingPeriodID AND paymentAllocationDetails.[Status] = 1 AND paymentTypes.[PaymentTypeFlag] <> 3 OR
         paymentAllocationDetails.[Year]  * 100 + paymentAllocationDetails.[WorkingPeriodTitle] = @Year * 100 + @WorkingPeriodID AND paymentTypes.[PaymentTypeFlag] = 3) AND
        (paymentAllocation.[PaymentCommandType] = @PaymentCommandType OR paymentAllocation.[PaymentTypesGuid] IN (SELECT * FROM com_udfSplit(@PaymentTypeGuids,','))) AND
        ((paymentTypes.[AffectOnAmountNature] = 1) OR (paymentTypes.[AffectOnAmountNature] = 2 AND paymentAllocation.[Amount] > 0))
    GROUP BY paymentAllocation.[RetiredPersonnelGuid], paymentAllocationDetails.[PaymentAllocationGuid]
),
```

But in join section, under one condition `@PaymentCommandType = 1` I want to use `ret_PaymentAllocationDetails` instead `"AllocationDetails"`(the temp table above):

```
CASE WHEN(@PaymentCommandType = 1) THEN ret_PaymentAllocationDetails  ELSE AllocationDetails END AS paymentAllocationDetails ON paymentAllocation.[Guid] = paymentAllocationDetails.[PaymentAllocationGuid]
```

I used CASE WHEN but it didn't worked. How to handle this issue?

This is the whole procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ret_PayrollCalculations_GetPayrollItems]
(
    @SalariedGuid uniqueidentifier,
    @Year int,
    @WorkingPeriodID int,
    @PaymentCommandType int,
    @PaymentTypeGuids nvarchar(max),
    @PayrollItemGuid uniqueidentifier
)
 AS
IF(ISNULL(@PayrollItemGuid, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AND @PaymentCommandType = 1)
    SELECT @PayrollItemGuid = [Guid] FROM ret_PayrollItemPatterns WHERE [PaymentCommandType] = 1 AND ISNULL([Deleted], 0) = 0 AND [Active] = 1
;WITH AllocationDetails
AS
(
    SELECT
        lastPaymentAllocationDetails.*
    FROM (
    SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [PaymentAllocationGuid] ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [WorkingPeriodTitle] DESC) rowNumber
    FROM ret_vwPaymentAllocationDetails
) lastPaymentAllocationDetails
WHERE lastPaymentAllocationDetails.rowNumber = 1
), ValidPaymentAllocations AS(
    SELECT
        paymentAllocationDetails.[PaymentAllocationGuid],
        paymentAllocation.[RetiredPersonnelGuid],
        MAX(paymentAllocationDetails.ID) AS MaxPaymentAllocationDetailID,
        MAX(paymentAllocationDetails.[Year] * 100 + paymentAllocationDetails.[WorkingPeriodTitle]) AS [WorkingPeriodKey]
    FROM
        ret_PaymentAllocation AS paymentAllocation INNER JOIN
        CASE when(@PaymentCommandType = 1) THEN ret_PaymentAllocationDetails  ELSE AllocationDetails END AS paymentAllocationDetails ON paymentAllocation.[Guid] = paymentAllocationDetails.[PaymentAllocationGuid] INNER JOIN
        ret_PaymentTypes AS paymentTypes ON paymentAllocation.[PaymentTypesGuid] = paymentTypes.[Guid] INNER JOIN
        (SELECT MAX(ID) ID FROM ret_PaymentAllocationDetails GROUP BY PaymentAllocationGuid,WorkingPeriodTitle,Year) lastRecord ON LastRecord.Id     = paymentAllocationDetails.ID
    WHERE
        ISNULL(paymentAllocation.[Deleted],0) = 0 AND
        paymentAllocation.[RetiredPersonnelGuid] = @SalariedGuid AND
        (paymentAllocationDetails.[Year]  * 100 + paymentAllocationDetails.[WorkingPeriodTitle] <= @Year * 100 + @WorkingPeriodID AND paymentAllocationDetails.[Status] = 1 AND paymentTypes.[PaymentTypeFlag] <> 3 OR
         paymentAllocationDetails.[Year]  * 100 + paymentAllocationDetails.[WorkingPeriodTitle] = @Year * 100 + @WorkingPeriodID AND paymentTypes.[PaymentTypeFlag] = 3) AND
        (paymentAllocation.[PaymentCommandType] = @PaymentCommandType OR paymentAllocation.[PaymentTypesGuid] IN (SELECT * FROM com_udfSplit(@PaymentTypeGuids,','))) AND
        ((paymentTypes.[AffectOnAmountNature] = 1) OR (paymentTypes.[AffectOnAmountNature] = 2 AND paymentAllocation.[Amount] > 0))
    GROUP BY paymentAllocation.[RetiredPersonnelGuid], paymentAllocationDetails.[PaymentAllocationGuid]
), LastAmounts AS (
SELECT
    payrollCalculationDetails.[ItemGuid],
    SUM(payrollCalculationDetails.[Amount]) AS [Amount]
FROM
    ret_PayrollCalculationCommands payrollCalculationCommands INNER JOIN
    ret_PayrollCalculations payrollCalculations ON payrollCalculationCommands.[Guid] = payrollCalculations.[CalculationCommandGuid] INNER JOIN
    ret_PayrollCalculationDetails payrollCalculationDetails ON payrollCalculations.Guid = payrollCalculationDetails.[CalculationGuid]
WHERE 
    payrollCalculationCommands.[Hidden] = 0 AND
    payrollCalculationCommands.[Approved] = 1 AND
    payrollCalculations.[SalariedGuid] = @SalariedGuid AND
    payrollCalculations.[WorkingPeriodID] = @WorkingPeriodID AND
    payrollCalculations.[Year] = @Year
GROUP BY 
    payrollCalculationDetails.[ItemGuid]
)
SELECT
    paymentAllocation.[Guid],
    1 AS ItemType,
    paymentAllocation.[PaymentCommandType],
    '' AS ParameterName,
    paymentAllocationDetails.[Status],
    paymentAllocationDetails.[Amount],
    paymentAllocation.[Coffer],
    paymentTypes.[AffectOnSlipNature] AS [AffectOnSlip],
    paymentTypes.[AffectOnAmountNature] AS [AffectOnAmount],
    paymentTypes.[EffectiveOnSlip],
    paymentTypes.[BackPayable],
    0 AS [Reversible],
    lastAmounts.Amount AS LastAmount
FROM
    ret_PaymentAllocation AS paymentAllocation INNER JOIN
    ret_PaymentAllocationDetails AS paymentAllocationDetails ON paymentAllocation.[Guid] = paymentAllocationDetails.[PaymentAllocationGuid] INNER JOIN
    ValidPaymentAllocations AS validPaymentAllocations ON 
    paymentAllocationDetails.[PaymentAllocationGuid] = validPaymentAllocations.[PaymentAllocationGuid] AND 
    paymentAllocationDetails.[Year] * 100 + paymentAllocationDetails.WorkingPeriodTitle = validPaymentAllocations.[WorkingPeriodKey] AND 
    paymentAllocationDetails.ID = validPaymentAllocations.MaxPaymentAllocationDetailID INNER JOIN
    ret_PaymentTypes AS paymentTypes ON paymentAllocation.[PaymentTypesGuid] = paymentTypes.[Guid] LEFT JOIN 
    LastAmounts lastAmounts ON lastAmounts.ItemGuid = paymentAllocation.Guid
WHERE
    ISNULL(paymentAllocation.Active,0) = 1 AND
    paymentAllocation.[RetiredPersonnelGuid] = @SalariedGuid AND
    paymentAllocationDetails.[Status] = 1 /* Status.Save */
UNION ALL
SELECT
    payrollItems.[Guid],
    2 AS [ItemType],
    payrollItemPatterns.[PaymentCommandType],
    payrollItems.[ParameterName],
    0 AS [Status],
    0 AS [Amount],
    0 AS [Coffer],
    payrollItems.[Nature] AS [AffectOnSlip],
    0 AS [AffectOnAmount],
    payrollItems.[EffectiveOnSlip],
    payrollItems.[BackPayable],
    payrollItems.[Reversible],
    lastAmounts.Amount AS LastAmount
FROM
    ret_PayrollItemPatterns AS payrollItemPatterns INNER JOIN
    ret_PayrollItemPatternDetails AS PID ON payrollItemPatterns.[Guid] = PID.[PayrollItemPatternGuid] INNER JOIN
    ret_PayrollItems AS payrollItems ON PID.[PayrollItem] = payrollItems.ID LEFT JOIN 
    LastAmounts lastAmounts ON lastAmounts.ItemGuid = payrollItems.Guid
WHERE
    (payrollItemPatterns.[PaymentCommandType] = @PaymentCommandType AND payrollItemPatterns.[Guid] IN (@PayrollItemGuid))
```

Comment: You can't "parameterize" the joining of a table, you'll have to join both tables, then use COALESCE in the select to pick the values you want according to what `@PaymentCommandType` is set to

Comment: You talk about temporary tables, but there aren't any in your SQL. Are we missing something here?

Comment: Pet peeve as well, `;` is a statement **terminator**, it goes at the **end** of *all* your statements, not the start of those that require the *previous* statement to be properly terminated.

Comment: Tip as well. When choosing aliases it helps if you make them succinct but still meaningful. This means that your entire code becomes more succinct too. For example, rather than`PaymentAllocation` for `ret_PaymentAllocation` (which barely is an alias) something like `rPA` or `PA` would be far better choices.

Comment: I put the whole procedure in the question.

Comment: @CaiusJard it is possible that both join return non-null values, If it's possible explain more to solve this issue.

Comment: The bigger concern would be if one join fails, as it will remove the row for the other join. Use left join in that case

Comment: *"I put the whole procedure in the question."* There's still no temporary tables though. Are you, perhaps, under the impression that a Common Table Expression (CTE) and a Temporary Table are the same thing? They aren't; they are *very* different. A CTE, as it's names suggests, is an expression. A Temporary Table is an actual physical object that would be stored in `tempdb` for the duration of its existence. How they work "under the hood" and how they behave are both *very* different.

Comment: Changing it to an `IF/ELSE` with two separate queries is probably the most performant method

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explanation of the theory using a contrived example (because it's easier than trying to understand your exact situation and writing a query that uses your exact tables - you can hopefully translate this advice into what you want)

Imagine you have 3 tables: Person, WorkAddress, HomeAddress. We will ignore observations that the two different addresses should be in the same table with a discriminator for this contrived example

You want to pass a parameter to dictate what data is returned-work or home

You cannot do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  Person p
  JOIN CASE WHEN @what = 'work' THEN WorkAddress ELSE HomeAddress END x
    ON p.Id = x.PersonId
```

Nice try, but you can't "return an entire table" from a case when

You have to join both, and then pick out in the select, what you want:

```
SELECT 
  p.*,
  CASE WHEN @what = 'work' THEN w.Building ELSE h.Building END as Building,
  CASE WHEN @what = 'work' THEN w.Street ELSE h.Street END as Street,
  ...
FROM
  Person p
  JOIN WorkAddress w ON p.Id = w.PersonId
  JOIN HomeAddress h ON p.Id = h.PersonId
```

If an address is missing, you need to LEFT JOIN it, otherwise the missing (work) address will cause the entire person and (available) home address to disappear from the results.

Larnu reasonably points out that LEFT JOINing will allow you to put the parameter into the ON clause, which *may* allow your DB to optimize it (never perform the join if the parameter comparison is false)

```
SELECT 
  p.*,
  COALESCE(w.Building, h.Building) as Building,
  COALESCE(w.Street, h.Street) as Street,
  ...
FROM
  Person p
  LEFT JOIN WorkAddress w ON p.Id = w.PersonId AND @what = 'work'
  LEFT JOIN HomeAddress h ON p.Id = h.PersonId AND @what = 'home'
```

Charlieface alo makes the reasonable point that you shouldn't do this at all; do an IF/ELSE if you're writing a stored procedure as it's the most reliable way of being sure about the query planning and performance optimizations that will take place. You can use a CTE for the parts common to both queries so it makes the whole thing easier to read

Comment: Hmm, this would work for one-to-one relationships, but not one to many. If someone, for example, had 2 Home Addresses, and you asked for the Work address you would get 2 (identical) rows. If someone had 2 home and 2 work addresses, then you'd end up with 4 rows what ever you asked for.

Comment: @Larnu this is my exact problem, despite I select Max(Id) to handle this issue, it returns two rows and ruined every thing.

Comment: thank you I will try it and let you know the result.

Comment: @Larnu then you run a subquery to pick out the row you want (the most recent address for example)

Comment: I think you wanted to direct that to @mehrabhabibi , not me, Caius Jard . But I would personally suggest moving the parameter clause to the `ON`, and using a `LEFT JOIN`. Then only rows from the correct table are returned. Of course, you'd need to also then use a `COALESCE`/`ISNULL` in the `SELECT`.

Comment: And then coalescing.. But it's the same end result

Comment: Not for the query you have, no, @CaiusJard , it wouldn't result in possible duplication.

Comment: Of course it would, if @what was 'work' and workaddress had 2 rows.. but we've covered this by squashing the 1:M to 1:1 with a relevant subquery

Comment: @Larnu I did intend to direct the original comment to you because you were the one proposing the cartesian explosion - the answer was intended to focus on "you can't parameterize a join", not also include "and here is an exhaustive list of how to solve every other problem you might encounter while writing an SQL". If we expanded the scope of SO answers thus every answer would be a book. At some point you have to stop and say "OK, that part works.. here is a new problem that it has realized" and ask another question on it. It shouldn't even be another question because the OP knows `rownumber=1`

Comment: @mehrabhabibi for an easy life, make sure the "tables" you join in have one row. I'm sure you know how to do that because your question already contains a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ... WHERE ronwumber=1` CTE

Comment: I would, personally, suggest that expanding an answer to deal with one-to-many relationships (very common in an RDBMS), isn't creating a "book", @CaiusJard, but that's your opinion. I was just offering my thoughts on when this might not work, and it seems, from the OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174715/how-to-use-specific-table-in-a-join-under-condition/68175186?noredirect=1#comment120492385_68175186) I hit the nail on the head; perhaps they are using a one-to-one relationship though, and then yes my points are moot.

Comment: @Larnu If you check the question and the comments it defines the scope of the answer: I commented "you can't do that, do this", OP said "can you explain more", I wrote an answer expanding on "do this". If OP subequently runs into a cartesian explosion that (inexplicably, given they demonstrate ability to handle) they cannot handle, it is a separate question. This question is solely about why `JOIN CASE WHEN x THEN t1 ELSE t2 END` doesn't work and how it could; we should not let questions become a set of ever shifting goalposts until we have written the OP's entire airport management system.

Comment: @mehrabhabibi (but if you cannot do that; ask a new question please.. it is a separate problem to what you ask about here which is a syntax error that prevents your SQL running at all)